# UIElement null when using custom DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, user-controls

I have created a simple usercontrol for tooltip:

```
public partial class TooltipControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipControlContentProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTipControlContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(TooltipControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata(new Grid()));


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipProperty
      = DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTip", typeof(string), typeof(TooltipControl),
          new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Tooltip
    {
        get { return GetValue(ToolTipProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(ToolTipProperty, value); }
    }

    public FrameworkElement ToolTipControlContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(ToolTipControlContentProperty) as FrameworkElement; }
        set { SetValue(ToolTipControlContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public TooltipControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

This is it's xaml:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
   x:Class="Dashboard.Controls.TooltipControl" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="150" Height="75">

        <Border Child="{Binding ToolTipControlContent}">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1BA1E2" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF096A99" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am using this control in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<local:TooltipControl Width="150" Height="75" x:Name="tileWidthSettings" Tooltip="Adjust the tile width of widgets" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <local:TooltipControl.ToolTipControlContent>
        <Grid Height="75" Width="150">

            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="8" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Grid.Effect>
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1BA1E2" Offset="0.004"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF096A99" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <StackPanel d:LayoutOverrides="Height" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tile width" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="13.333"/>
                <telerik:RadSlider x:Name="radSliderTileWidth" ValueChanged="radSliderTileWidth_ValueChanged" RepeatInterval="10" Value="300" Minimum="0" Margin="0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </local:TooltipControl.ToolTipControlContent>
</local:TooltipControl>
```

If I directly use:

```
radSliderTileWidth.Minimum = 1.0;
```

in MainPage.xaml.cs I get NULL. Even though I can access the element directly through name it is always NULL. I do it in Loaded event handler.

Then I tried:

```
(tileWidthSettings.ToolTipControlContent.FindName("radSliderTileWidth" ) as RadSlider).Maximum = GetScreenWidth() / 2;
```

It was still NULL.

But, if I try it randomly in some event handler it works! Probably it is because the template of the usercontrol hasn't been applied in the loaded event.

Then I tried:

```
RadSlider slider = tileWidthSettings.ToolTipControlContent.FindChildByType<RadSlider>();
```

which is basically extension method and searches child using VisualTreeHelper it works!

So what am I doing wrong here? How can I get my radSliderTileWidth in my MainPage.xaml.cs which works in a unified way whether in Loaded event or in other event handlers?

Btw, I am using Silverlight 4.0 but I think this is a general concept which applies to WPF also. So I am tagging it as WPF also.

Comment: By the way, it is not advisable to set the `DataContext` on `UserControls`, if someone makes an instance of the control and expects the DataContext to be inherited that will not be the case and it will be invisible, too. e.g. `<local:TooltipControl ToolTipControlContent="{Binding MyToolTipPropOnVM}" />` will fail as the `DataContext` is the `ToolipControl` itself.

Comment: Thanks! I agree. Will correct that in my control.

Comment: @H.B: Btw, what approach do you suggest if I want to bind my code behind in xaml without setting datacontext?

Comment: I tend to name the `UserControl` and use `ElementName` when binding, but you could also use `RelativeSource` to the `AncestorType` of your `UserControl`. Don't know which is "better".

Comment: I don't want to use ElementName because if I give name to the usercontrol then try to add new instance of usercontrol it would throw exception. AncestorType is not supported in Silverlight 4. I am using SL4.

Comment: Don't you need to name `UserControl` instances with `x:Name` anyway?

Comment: Nope. I don't want to name it. Consider a tooltip control. There will be many instances of Tooltip control. Not necessarily I want to them. Naming them won't do any good to me.

Comment: You don't need to name the instances of the control, only in the declaration `<UserControl Name="control" ....`

Answer (score 0):

See the MSDN doc of [FrameworkElement.Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=VS.95).aspx) in Silverlight, section "Loaded and Control Object Lifetime":

> The timing of the Loaded event in Silverlight differs from the timing of the FrameworkElement.Loaded event in WPF. Specifically, the WPF Loaded event occurs after the template is applied. In Silverlight, the Loaded event is not guaranteed to occur after the template is applied. This might be an issue for you if you are using the Loaded event for a relatively common control scenario: you want to examine the visual tree, either to get a value as a source for something else or to change a value in the templated composition where you can know the new value only at run time. In this case, calls to the Silverlight VisualTreeHelper methods to examine the visual tree of the template content might not work if you make them directly from a Loaded handler.
>
> ...